# slideshow not fading after another enters

Tags: css, reactjs

first off, I'm trying to align the slideshow to the center of the page and I'm not sure how to implement it

that's how my web page looks right now:

[image: web page]

also, as you can see in the picture, the slide that was supposed to fade (blue one) is moving back to the right and I intend to make it unseen.

in this picture, the slides are supposed to go to the left (red arrows) but to be unseen when moving to the right (blue arrows).
[image: example]

Any idea how to implament it?

Here is my page:

```
import "./Home.css";
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {Slideshow, SlideshowItem } from "../components/slideShow.js"
import BitCoinImg from "../images/bitcoin.jpg"
import ethImg from "../images/eth.jpg"
import litecoinImg from "../images/Litecoin.jpg"


function Home() {
  return(
    <div style={{textAlign:"center", fontFamily:"Comic Sans MC", fontSize:"100"}}>
      THIS IS THE HOME PAGE

      <nav>
        <Link to="/bitcoin" style={{margin: "10px"}}> Bitcoin </Link>
        <Link to="/litecoin" style={{margin: "10px"}}> LiteCoin </Link>
        <Link to="/ethereum" style={{margin: "10px"}}> Ethereum </Link>
      </nav>

      <Slideshow>
      <SlideshowItem>
          <img src= {BitCoinImg}/>
        </SlideshowItem>
        <SlideshowItem>
          <img src= {litecoinImg}/>
        </SlideshowItem>
        <SlideshowItem>
          <img src= {ethImg}/>
        </SlideshowItem>
      </Slideshow>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

And it's css file:

```
.gallery-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

.gallery-slider {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to show one image per slide so you should set your slider prop: items to show to 1, this will make your slider to initial the items in the right width and the next or prev images won't be seen anymore.

in case you can't set this props to your slider, you should work on slider container and slide item with by styling to limit image display.